# Town name from lat/long coordinates in R (without using google maps API)

Tags: r, gis

Are there any ways to obtain a city name or address from a pair of coordinates in R, without using ggmap or other packages that rely on the google maps API?

Answer (score 1):

The Census Bureau has an geocoding API that is accessible with the `censusxy` package. See [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/censusxy/vignettes/censusxy.html) and the Census Bureau's [Geocoder page](https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

For reverse geocoding you can try `revgeo` function from `revgeo` package.